# Rav Scheinberg on pesach

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, passover

Rav Scheinberg zt”l says the proper time for starting the seider is at after tzeis hakochavim (three stars emerge). Upon arriving home from Ma’ariv one should start the Seder promptly in order that the children should not fall asleep before eating the matzah, marror and the meal. Therefore one should say the haggdah as quickly as possible, and save the commentaries for later.

What is the source for this?

Comment: @GershonGold: Where did in halachah did he get his p'sak from?

Comment: Seems quite obvious

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[מ"ב ס' תע"ב ס"ק ג' ושעה"צ אות ב](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14165&st=&pgnum=158)

Comment: That only says that have to be up for the Mah Nishtane. I think it is a chiddush to say they have to be up for the Matzah, Morror and the meal.

Comment: @Yishai: Read the end of the Shaar hatziyun where it clearly says to hurry and eat the Matza

Comment: He leaves it by a Tzorich Iyun, but the psak in the Mishna Brurah isn't that way. I don't understand how you are reading to be a clear source. Perhaps you can expand on that in the answer?